# Creating an installer for JavaScript-based app

Tags: javascript, windows-installer, installation

I know nothing about installers. I have created a Windows desktop "app" which is actually JavaScript based window wrapped in a container to look like an app (under Chrome).

There are two versions, one for users who may be offline, so there is a local IndexedDB database, and many settings are defined in localStorage.

The other version is for back-office, always online, but the wrapper is also local, and there is one variable stored in localStorage, which is the username.

I need two installers, one for each version, the idea is to copy all these files into a folder, and then execute an html page which has the JavaScript which initializes the local variables (creates IndexedDB tables and sets the localStorage variables).

As first step, it needs to ask for a password, compare it with the server, and then install the variables per specific user (this is done by JavaScript).

How do I do all of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider creating an electron Application.

https://electron.atom.io/

Then theres "electron builder" which creates packaged, ready to install files from your Application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder

> I have created a Windows desktop "app" which is actually JavaScript
>   based window wrapped in a container to look like an app (under
>   Chrome).

Or is this, what you are allready doing?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much what I have now.
What I need actually, now that I am thinking about it, is just an autoextract which would copy my files to a certain folder and a shortcut on the desktop for installation.

Comment: Can't you use something like a npm task, to move the packaged files? Maybe i dont understand the problem here.

Comment: I did what you suggested, and added what I needed, thanks!